# Plotly.js draw shape to ymax

Tags: plot, plotly, shapes, plotly.js

In plotly.js i want do draw a rectangle, that goes from a certain y-coordinate to the top of the plot (i.e. max y that is displayed). Following figure shows what i currently have. [image: Plot with rectangle] And here the code that i am using to draw it:

```
{
type: 'rect',
xref: 'x',
yref: 'y',
x0: 0,
y0: 0,
x1: 5,
y1: 9000,
// ... visuals
}
```

Instead i want the y-coordinates of the rectangle to begin at 9000 (something like y0: 9000) and always end at the top of the plot (y1: ~12400), without having to manually declare y1. Is that possible?

Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 2):

`y0` and `y1` value `0-1` refer the `yaxis` amplitude.
So you can set `y0` and `y1` value `0-1` in your layout configuration of the shape and setting the `yref` as `'paper'`. Further documentation can be found [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-shapes-items-shape-yref).

```
 {
    type: 'rect',
    xref: 'x',
    yref: 'paper',
    x0: 0,
    y0: 0, //y0: 0~1 range
    x1: 5,
    y1: 1,//y1: 0~1 range
    // ... visuals
    }
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/mdnasirfardoush/pen/YvgMYM/?editors=0010)

Comment: To be little more clear this range for `y0` and `y1` works only if the `yref` is set to `'paper'` and not `'y'`